# Как задать вывести массив с неопределенным изначально количеством переменных?

Tags: c++, массивы

Задача заключается в том, что юзер вводит количество учеников, тем самым задавая размерночть массива и в последствии сам же заполняет массив. При таком коде выдает ошибку указываю на mas[], подскажите ошибку

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    int mas[];
    int n;
    cout << "Ввудите количество учеников" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cout << "Введите оценки учеников" << endl;
        cin >> mas[i];
    }
    cout << mas[];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: std::list, std::vector и прочие контейнеры вас определенно спасут

Comment: Код в вопрос надо вставлять текстом, а не картинкой...

Comment: @Qwertiy можешь подтвердить peer review

Comment: @outoftime, готово. Хотя его бы со временем и так подтвердили.

Answer (score 1):

Объявить как указатель

```
int *mas;
```

и динамически выделить под него память:

```
cin >> n;
mas = new int[n];
```

Answer (score 0):

Как задать:

```
  int *mas = new int[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> mas[i];
```

Как вывести:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cout << mas[i];
```

А вообще тема динамических массивов достаточно подробно изучена в таких местах как [Google](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2), [Яндекс](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2&lr=213), [StackOverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%20%5Bc%2B%2B%5D%20%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2), а так же в учебниках в разделах, где содержится кодовое словосочетание «динамический массив».

Comment: Стрелки не в ту сторону...

Comment: `Ctrl+C` с `cout`a :D